# insert hyphens between each space on sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have a text like this:
**this is any text**

Could sublime text convert it to?
**this-is-any-text**

insert hyphens between each space

Comment: Use find/replace to find spaces and replace with dashes?

Comment: I use this but is php, 

```<?php
$text = "[link to text on uniq.edu.mx]";

$text = preg_replace_callback("~\[([^\]]*)]~", function($s) {
    return ''.str_replace(" ", "-", $s[1]).' ';
    }, $text);

print $text;
  ?>```

Comment: If you want to constrain it you can select the text you want it to affect first and then use the option to use the selection. You can also just select the first space manually and then use `quick add next` to add the remaining spaces one at a time, and press `-` once you're done to replace them all at once. In any case, it would help if your question was more specific about what you're trying to do in a case like this

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions given in the comments, there is another option - the [`Case Conversion`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Case%20Conversion) plugin. **`Edit → Convert Case`** contains Title Case, Upper Case, Lower Case, and Swap Case. `Case Conversion` provides:

- snake_case
- SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE
- camelCase
- PascalCase
- dot.case
- dash-case
- separate words
- separate with forward slashes
- separate with backslashes

To use it, simply highlight the section of text you want to convert and select the desired operation from the menu, or use the assigned keyboard shortcut, which will show up on the menu. You can combine this with Find by using a regex pattern to only select certain areas.

Note: While I have contributed to the [`Case Conversion` repo](https://github.com/jdavisclark/CaseConversion) (I [added](https://github.com/jdavisclark/CaseConversion/pull/22) the backslash feature), I am not its author, just a very satisfied user.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, weird that it didn't get upvoted at all. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have done as indicated by **@odatnurd** in sublime text I have **selected** the first space, then the following with ***CTRL + D*** and finally when they have all been selected I put a hyphen **-** and they have all been converted to a hyphen